# How to get the newly loaded page on pageinit?

Tags: jquery-mobile

On page 1, when ajax loading to page 2, I need to get the `[data-role=page]` element of page 2,

but on `pageinit`(or `pagecreate`), the `$.mobile.activePage` is still page 1.

How to get **the newly loaded page instead of the current page** on `pageinit`?

```
$(document).on('pageinit', function () {
    console.log($.mobile.activePage);  // page 1
});
```

Comment: How do you load the page?

Comment: @Omar Either `<a href"2">`  or `<a href="2" data-rel="dialog">`

Comment: You want to retrieve the dialog before navigating it or only one time once it's created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to retrieve it one time only, then use `pagecreate` because it fires once per page and it fires before navigation is commenced.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function (e) {
  if ( $(e.target).hasClass("ui-dialog") ) {
    var dialog = $(e.target);
  }
});
```

To retrieve it every time you navigate to it, you can use othe pageContainer events. In case you want to alter the page you're nacigating to, use `pagecobtainerbeforechange`.

```
$(document).on("pagecintainerbeforechange", function (e, data) {
  if ( typeof data.toPage == "object" && typeof data.prevPage != "undefined" && data.toPage.hasClass("ui-dialog") ) {
    data.toPage.find(".foo").addClass(".bar");
  }
});
```

For other events in case you just want to access dialog and manipulate its markup.

```
$(document).on("pagecontainerbeforeshow pagecontainershow", function (e, data) {
   if ( data.toPage.hasClass("ui-dialog") ) {
     var dialog = data.toPage;
     /* do something */
});
```

Comment: I need to do something on **every** clicked page, and also on the first page, that is, on all pages of the site.  Some pages are opened as a dialog, some as a standard page with data-transition=xx.  The thing to do is to apply [date selector plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-DateBox/).  Ideally datebox should apply only once on each page, so when _from page 3 click to page 4_, apply datebox to page 4; _from page 4 open page 5 as a dialog_, apply datebox to page 5; _close page 5 dialog_, **do not apply** datebox on page 4.  (cont...)

Comment: (...cont)  I can avoid repeated initialization by `$(...).not('.inited').datebox(...).addClass('inited')`, but just want to know if there is a way to avoid so by certain jQuery mobile page events.

Comment: Then use pagecreate as it fires once per page/dialog. @KaFaiLo

Comment: [**Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/xpwhrSaudvxXys0EtFGS)   ▊   _a to b, b back to a_  -> no alert on a, ok  ▊ _a to b, b to c, c back to b_   -> **not ok**, since alert on b.  But strange, as now _b back to a_ does not alert.  @Omar

Comment: @KaFaiLo pls update your question with demo and code. Also elaborate on what you want to achieve exactly. Without clear code and explanation, it's difficult to provide rock-solid solution.

Comment: `$(e.target)` is the answer of this question.

Comment: Elaborated the alert/no alert question in [another post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27297772/running-something-only-when-a-page-is-newly-made-not-when-going-back-from-anoth)  @Omar